# FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using rails 5. We are using rds Postgres which has max connection limit 801. As I can see so many commits are in idle state.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: While performing load testing we are getting **FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections** frequently

Comment: That's because you're creating connections and not closing them. Eventually you run out of connections.

Comment: What is the best solution while using rails?

Comment: Any other way to handle?

Comment: Use a connection pool. Close connections you don't need any more.